# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

can not able to regenerate token, an issue in split. in error , which is showing split is undefined. how can solve issue in split. below mention my codes & issues. how can solve issue in split? here how can regenerate  token from existing code?

Error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') in node.js

error occur in below code:

```
 const cookies = request.headers.cookie;
 const token = cookies.split('=')[1]
```

server.js code:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cookieParser()) //cookie parser is used to protect user details from hacker
//middleware - urlencoded for form submission & json for api calling
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json({extended:true}))
//app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(express.json())

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }))

//router
app.use('/api/employee', require('./routes/employeeRoute'))
app.use('/api/user', require('./routes/userRoute'))

// mongodb connection
connectDB()

// port connection
PORT = process.env.PORT
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening to port number: ${PORT}`))
```

userRouter.js

```
const express = require('express');
const userController = require('../controllers/userController')
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', userController.signup);
router.post('/login',userController.Login);
router.get('/profile',userController.verifyToken,userController.getUser);
//verify token is used for after refresh the page, user can able to view user details.
router.get('/refresh',userController.refreshToken,userController.verifyToken,userController.getUser)
router.post('/logout', userController.Logout)
 module.exports = router;
```

userController.js

```
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
//const { request, response } = require('express');
//const JWT_SECRET_KEY = 'secret key'

// Registration for new user
//next is used for next step of middleware
const signup = async (request, response, next) => {
    const { name, email, password } = request.body;
    let existingUser;
    try {
        existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    if (existingUser) {
        console.log('User already exists', existingUser)
        return response.status(400).json({ message: 'User already exists! Login Instead' })
    }
    const hashedPassword =  bcrypt.hashSync(password)
    const newuser = new User({
        name, // name: name , password: password
        email,
        password: hashedPassword
    })
    try {
        await newuser.save()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

    return response.status(201).json({ message: newuser })
}

//Login user after registration
const Login = async (request, response, next) => {
    const { email, password } = request.body;

    let existingUser;
    try {
        existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return new Error(error)
    }

    if (!existingUser) {
        return response.status(400).json({ message: 'User not found. Signup please...' })
    }

    const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(password, existingUser.password)

    if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
        return response.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid email or password' })
    }
    //HSA256 token
    const token = jwt.sign({ id: existingUser._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, {
        expiresIn: '1h'
    })

    console.log("Generated Token\n", token);
    if(request.cookies[`${existingUser._id}`]){
        request.cookies[`${existingUser._id}`] = "";
    }

    response.cookie(String(existingUser.id),token,{
        path:'/',
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 30), // 30 seconds
        httpOnly: true, // it is overall accessable from frontend
        sameSite: 'lax'
    })
    return response.status(200).json({ message: 'Successfully Logined In', user: existingUser, token })
}

//baerer token is used authorization
const verifyToken = (request, response, next) => { // verify the user token
   
    // const headers = request.headers[`authorization`];
    //  //console.log('token',headers)
     // generate token to the login user
    //const token = headers.split(" ")[1]
    const cookies = request.headers.cookie;
    const token = cookies.split('=')[1]    // split the token for verify the token,here zero index contain 1st element. 
    //console.log(token);
    if (!token) {
        response.status(404).json({ message: 'No token found' });
    }
    // decode information indicated as user
    jwt.verify(String(token), process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Invalid Token')
            return response.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid Token' })
        }
        console.log(user.id);
        request.id = user.id; // decoded the id
    })
    next()//next is used to move next middleware getUser
}

const getUser = async (request, response, next) =>{
    const userId = request.id;
    let user;
    try {
        user = await User.findById(userId,"-password") // -password is used for display all details of user without password

    } catch (error) {
        return new Error(error)
    }
    // validate  
    if(!user){
        return response.status(404).json({message:'User Not Found'})
    }
    return response.status(200).json({user})
}

const refreshToken = (request, response, next) => { 
    const cookies = request.headers.cookie;
    const prevToken = cookies.split("=")[1];
    if (!prevToken) {
      return response.status(400).json({ message: "Couldn't find token" });
    }
    jwt.verify(String(prevToken), process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return response.status(403).json({ message: "Authentication failed" });
      }
      response.clearCookie(`${user.id}`);
      request.cookies[`${user.id}`] = "";
  
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, {
        expiresIn: "35s",
      });
      console.log("Regenerated Token\n", token);
  
      response.cookie(String(user.id), token, {
        path: "/",
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 30), // 30 seconds
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "lax",
      });
  
      request.id = user.id;
      next();
    });
  };
  
const Logout = async (request,response,next)=>{
    const cookies = request.headers.cookie;
    const prevToken = cookies.split("=")[1];
    if (!prevToken) {
      return response.status(400).json({ message: "Couldn't find token" });
    }
    jwt.verify(String(prevToken), process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return response.status(403).json({ message: "Authentication failed" });
      }
      response.clearCookie(`${user.id}`);
      request.cookies[`${user.id}`] = "";
      return response.status(200).json({message:' Successfully Logout'})
      
    });
}

module.exports = { signup, Login, verifyToken , getUser, refreshToken, Logout}
```

Error:

```
Generated Token
 eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzZmUxMjMzNWRkYjBjZmNhYjZmY2I3ZCIsImlhdCI6MTY3ODExNDc1OCwiZXhwIjoxNjc4MTE4MzU4fQ.HVMpX6qUH6_lcAVM8IHRdrLtWSqpIQW3nGJtbfM1UiY  
63fe12335ddb0cfcab6fcb7d
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at verifyToken (F:\react class\project_employee\backend\controllers\userController.js:84:27)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\react class\project_employee\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (F:\react class\project_employee\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (F:\react class\project_employee\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)      
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\react class\project_employee\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at F:\react class\project_employee\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (F:\react class\project_employee\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (F:\react class\project_employee\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (F:\react class\project_employee\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)     
    at router (F:\react class\project_employee\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

Comment: There is a lot of code that seems rather unnecessary to reproducing the issue at hand - please boil the code down to a [mre]. Separately, how are you so sure that all requests to these endpoints will contain cookie data? Trying to split `undefined` will indeed result in this error, and `request.headers.cookie` will indeed be `undefined` if the client doesn't send cookies along with the requrest.

Comment: `// cookie parser is used to protect user details from hacker` This comment in your code demonstrates you have a rather dangerous misunderstanding of what a cookie parser is, how it works, and what security it provides. I would **very strongly** recommend you take some time to understand these core principles before you potentially unwittingly expose your users' data to an attacker. Security is an extremely important topic to understand and get right, even at small scales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are able to store or collect a cookie from the user, you will not have any issues. Here, you are trying to fetch a token from a cookie which may not always be available. If I understand the method name correctly, you are trying to fetch and verify the token, for which you do not need to parse the cookie.

Here is the implementation that I used in my app. Please try it and see if it resolves your issue.

```js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let token = req.header("Authorization");

    if (!token) {
      return res.status(403).send("Access Denied");
    }

    if (token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      token = token.slice(7, token.length).trimLeft();
    }

    const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    req.user = verified;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};
```